# Java: Convert "Europe/London" to 3 digit timezone

Tags: java, timezone

How can I convert the timezone identifiers to the corresponding 3 digit string?
For example "Europe/London" => "GMT"

Comment: If London has Daylight Savings Time, "Europe/London" != "GMT"

Comment: Yep @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen. It would be BST

Answer (score 5):

See the `String getDisplayName(boolean daylight,int style)` method in `java.util.TimeZone`. The style may be `TimeZone.LONG` or `TimeZone.SHORT` with the short style returning the short name of the time zone.

---

A more long winded approach is to check the output of `String[] TimeZone.getAvailableIDs(int offset)`. The short time zone codes can be ambiguous or redundant, so maybe you might want to be more thorough about it:

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London");
for (String s : TimeZone.getAvailableIDs(tz.getOffset(System.currentTimeMillis()))) {
    System.out.print(s + ",");
}

------------------------------------------------------

Africa/Abidjan,Africa/Accra,Africa/Bamako,Africa/Banjul,Africa/Bissau,
Africa/Casablanca,Africa/Conakry,Africa/Dakar,Africa/El_Aaiun,Africa/Freetown,
Africa/Lome,Africa/Monrovia,Africa/Nouakchott,Africa/Ouagadougou,Africa/Sao_Tome,
Africa/Timbuktu,America/Danmarkshavn,Atlantic/Canary,Atlantic/Faeroe,
Atlantic/Faroe,Atlantic/Madeira,Atlantic/Reykjavik,Atlantic/St_Helena,
Eire,Etc/GMT,Etc/GMT+0,Etc/GMT-0,Etc/GMT0,Etc/Greenwich,Etc/UCT,
Etc/UTC,Etc/Universal,Etc/Zulu,Europe/Belfast,
Europe/Dublin,Europe/Guernsey,Europe/Isle_of_Man,Europe/Jersey,Europe/Lisbon,
Europe/London,GB,GB-Eire,GMT,GMT0,Greenwich,Iceland,Portugal,UCT,UTC,
Universal,WET,Zulu,
```

Comment: this returns "MESZ" for "Europe/London"

Comment: Curious. And when the input is `MESZ` the long output is `Greenwich Mean Time`

Comment: Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to find 3 digit abbreviation for any timezone.

```
Date date = new Date(); 

String TimeZoneIds[] = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();

String timezoneShortName = "";

String timezoneLongName  = "Europe/London";

for (int i = 0; i < TimeZoneIds.length; i++) {
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(TimeZoneIds[i]);
    String tzName = tz.getDisplayName(tz.inDaylightTime(date),TimeZone.SHORT);

    if(timezoneLongName.equals(TimeZoneIds[i])){
        timezoneShortName = tzName;
        break;
    }
}
System.out.println(timezoneShortName);
```

Comment: The problem here though is that when you do:`Date date = new Date();`, that is applying the timezone of whatever device you are on. so when you perform the `tz.inDaylightTime(date)` bit, that is only figuring out whether or not your current device is in daylight saving time and NOT whether or not that time will be daylight savings time in **"Europe/London"**. So for instance if I run this code on a PC in New York and have my PC timezone set for EDT, then this code will determine the DST status in New York and not for "Europe/London"... Any thoughts on how to get around that!?!

Comment: @johnvdenley `Date` represents an absolute point in time (milliseconds since epoch, internally), so this is not an issue.  To put it another way, if I call `new Date()` in Boston and my friend calls `new Date()` in London at the same instant, our `Date` objects will have the same underlying timestamp.

Comment: Sure, but that is not the problem I am trying to solve. My problem was that the Date was stored on the server (UTC) but when that same date is served on a client PC, then the clients PC is applying the local timezone, which is fine, if you want the relative time. HOWEVER, here is the usecase for my product: I book a hair appointment in London for 4pm Friday, I go to New York on Monday, I forget when the appointment was so I log into the system & it tells me its at 9pm Friday! Alternatively, the server sends me a text to tell me that the appointment is at 8pm (because the server is UTC)